# Laravel 8 Dynamic relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8. I have relationships strings but I don't how to load the relationships inside a loop. I'd like to `explode()` my relationships on the dot and load each relationship to get the column

```
$userPostTitle = 'post.title';
$userAvatarFilename = 'profil.avatar.filename';
```

The idea is to use `explode()` on the dot `explode('.', $userPostTitle)` and add bracket object dynamically for each relationship :

```
    // for the userPostTitle we need two level
    $postTitle = $user->{explode[0]}->{explode[1]};

    // for the userAvatarFilename we need three level
     $avatarFilename = $user->{explode[0]}->{explode[1]}->{explode[2]};
```

How it's possible to add dynamically the exploded relationship ? `{rel1}->{rel2}->{rel3}` etc... Maybe there is a better solution than using `explode()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that your solution possibly does a lot of queries if you haven't preloaded the relations beforehand. However I think you can use the Laravel helper `object_get()` for your problem:

```php
$relation = 'profile.avatar.filename';
$avatarFilename = object_get($user, $relation);
// Which roughly translates to calling `$user->profile->avatar->filename`
```

It also accepts a third parameter which is a default value if the property turns out to be null.

Comment: Oh ok nice thank you for your answer. And the related function with laravel 8  `data_get()` right ?

Comment: I've never used that one in my code; I think it allows access both to arrays and objects, so you could call `data_get($obj, 'a.b.c')` to retrieve `$data->a['b']->c` or $data['a']['b']->c` depending on what the object contains. Most often you just need `object_get()` or `array_get()`. Also note that you can sometimes fallback to PHP 8's "null safe" operator like `$user?->profile?->avatar?->filename` which is the fastest language struct to retrieve the property when you are not sure if the inbetween properties exist (however you cant use this if you are required to work with a dot-syntax string)